# TypeError: Is not a function error in Unit testing with Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am getting 2 Errors everytime I run my test :

Error 1... >>>TypeError: this.part.list().subscribe is not a function

Error 2... >>>Error:  : could not find an object to spy upon for list()
>>>Usage: spyOn(,)

The part.service.ts contains the following code :

```
*export class PartService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configuration: Configuration) {
    }
    list(): Observable<Part[]> {
        console.log(this.configuration);
        const link = this.configuration.partApi + '/list';
        return this.http.get(link).pipe(
            map((result:Part[]) => {
                return result.map((element:Part)=>{
                    return <Part> Object.assign(new Part(), element);
                });
            })
        );
    }
}*
```

In my .spec.ts file I have the following code : -

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatFormField,MatTableModule, MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material';
import { PartViewComponent } from './partview.component';
import {PartService} from 'src/app/service/part.service';
import {DebugElement} from '@angular/core';
import { UuidPipe } from 'src/app/uuid.pipe';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Configuration } from 'src/app/app.configuration';
import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Part } from 'src/app/model';



class MockPartservice {

    list():Part {
     let part1:Part;
      part1=new Part();
      part1.description="This is a test data";
      part1.name="Hello";
      part1.uuid="ABCD1234";
        return part1;
    }

};

describe('PartviewComponent', () => {
  //let component: PartViewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PartViewComponent>;
  let partservice:PartService;
  let debugElement:DebugElement;
      partservice=null;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({

      imports:[MatFormFieldModule,MatTableModule],
      declarations:[UuidPipe,PartViewComponent],
      providers: [ PartViewComponent, {provide: PartService, useClass: MockPartservice}]

})
    .compileComponents();

  }));


  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PartViewComponent);
    
    debugElement=fixture.debugElement;
    partservice=fixture.debugElement.injector.get(PartService);
    
  });

 it('#list should return stubbed value from a spy', ()=>{

    
    const partServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('PartService',['list']);
    spyOn(partservice,'list').and.returnValue(Part);
    
    
 });


 })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While doing Unit testing with Jasmine should I mock or spy or stub my service which is injected in my component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506316/while-doing-unit-testing-with-jasmine-should-i-mock-or-spy-or-stub-my-service-wh)

Comment: please don't vandalise your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MockPartservice {

    list():Obserable<Part>{
      let part1:Part;
      part1=new Part();
      part1.description="This is a test data";
      part1.name="Hello";
      part1.uuid="ABCD1234";
      return of(part1);
    }

};
```

You need to return a `Observable` and return data using `of()` operator.And both need to be import from 'rxjs'

and you don't need to use  `spyOn`

Answer (score 0):

**After fixture creation call**  `fixture.detectChanges();`

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentName);
component = fixture.componentInstance;

//call detect changes here
fixture.detectChanges();
```